Can I determine if two formulas are the same using truth tables when both have different variables?
I know that i can check if two formulas are the same using truth tables when both formulas have the same variables. My doubt  is if I can determine , for example , if these formulas are the same:
A AND B
A AND B AND (C OR NOT C )

The example above is quite simple, but the point I'm trying to make should still come across. If I have two formulas that have different variables, but are essentially the same because some variables can be simplified, how can I verify this?

"C or not-C" is always True and "X and True" is equivalent to X, for a formula X whatever.

The first formula has free variables $A$ and $B$, so it has an interpretation in any context where $A$ and $B$ are propositional variables. Similarly, the second formula makes sense in any context where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are propositional variables. So if you take the union of both contexts, you get a context $A : \mathrm{Prop}, B : \mathrm{Prop}, C : \mathrm{Prop}$ where both formulas make sense and can be compared for equivalence.

And how can I make that comparison? If i build the truth tables , both have different dimmensions

What do you mean? You have three variables, so three dimensions.

Presumably you've been taught to build two truth tables and then compare. But you can always get away with just one truth table in which you put the union of the variables that appear in the formulas. For example, here the first formula contains $A, B$ and the second $A, B, C$. So make a truth table in which the first three columns are the variables $A, B, C$ (so you should have $2^3 = 8$ rows), the fourth column is $A \land B$ and the fifth $(A \land B) \land (C \lor \neg C)$. You'll simply evaluate $A \land B$ independently of the value of $C$, so you'll have a lot of duplicate rows for that expression, but it shouldn't have any effect on the end result.
Alternatively, you can still make two truth tables, but add the extra column for $C$ in the one for $A \land B$ and simply ignore it when evaluating $A \land B$ in each row, which will again give you a lot of duplicated values in that table, but that's again okay.
